# How can I have values dynamically in array in jqplot bar chart?

Tags: jquery, jqplot, bar-chart

I am using jqplot to create bar chart.

The code is as below.

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

var user1 = ['17','12','3'];
var user2 = ['45','12','5'];
var user3 = ['35','10','4'];
var user4 = ['25','12','8'];

    var ticks = ['Submission','Sentouts','Interviews'];
    plot2 = $.jqplot('chart3', [user1,user2,user3,user4], {
        seriesColors:['#35A6C5', '#FF0000', '#35A612', '#000000'],
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
            fillToZero: true,
            barWidth: 10,
            highlightMouseDown: true   
            },

            pointLabels: { show: true },

        },
```

Here, I have done hardcoding and and taken 4 users only.

How can I have users dynamically? also the values(numbers) in array with each users will be dynamically.

Please suggest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply make the data source a function to retrieve the data. Try something like this

```
plot2 = $.jqplot('chart3', getUserArrays(), {
    ....
}


function getUserArrays(){
    //create the dynamic data
    var users = [];

    //retrieve data for each user and then push to users array
    // ...

    return users;
}
```